# Laravel 5 Event - Is this a mediator or observer?

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel-5, observers, mediator

I was discussing Laravel's event system with another developer today. He mentioned that Laravel's event dispatcher uses an observer pattern.

I always thought it implemented a mediator pattern as your objects always listen/fire events through an event dispatcher object, but the doc says it is an observer.

```
Event::listen('event.name', function ($foo, $bar) {
    //
});

Event::fire("event.name", []);
```

Isn't this a mediator pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no precise idea about what Laravel's concretely do and actually if the doc says that it is built on an observer pattern, I would believe it.

However your question is about what the code looks like and from my experience I can easily recognize an observer here with the analogy :

- **listen** would be similar to **Observer's subscribe/attach**
- **fire** would be similar to **Observer's notify/update**

A mediator would seem weird to me here because even though the intent is to facilitate the communication between some objects, I can't see it as a good way to distribute notifications. I would definitely bet on an observer for that reason.

Comment: @floopy12 But don't you get an instance of an object and then listen on it if it is an observer? In this case, you are listening to an Event class, not an object that you are interested in. Having listen/fire does not mean that it is an observer. Mediator can have listen/fire as well.

Comment: @Moon In my opinion, the only thing that matters is that your are listening to something else even if it's not an "object", it means that your are somehow interested in. The Observer pattern (or any) does not belong to any language or paradigm, it's a conceptual idea to express a problem and a solution. The implementation should be tweaked to your specific needs. Here it seems to be more a "functiunal" approach where you listen to an event and associate a callback to it than a classic OOP implementation

Comment: @floopy12 // That I understand completely. The problem is that this implantation also implies somewhat loose compiling since the event name can be anything and Event is acting as a mediator whether I'm listening on a specific event or not.  I think this is why some of the PHP frameworks call it a mediator, but Laravel does not.

Comment: @Moon : Concerning the loose coupling thing, in both Mediator and Observer, objA and objB don't communicate directly (respectively through the Mediator or an "event" even if it is fired from the observable object). The code provided is not sufficient to know what Laravel actually do under the hood. However, given that a Mediator  facilitates the communication between two other objects (or more), where a the "two subjects" here if Event represents the mediator ? Moreover, would Event be a right name for a Mediator ? (Considering it's an acceptable name for an Observable)

Comment: @floopy12 // Not disagreeing, but not agreeing either. As far as I understand GOF book, observers do depend on each other. You need an instance of a subject to listen to. I understand that the implantation changes, but I don't really think intention should change. In this particular case, no one is actually depending on each other. It's just in a programmer's head. I guess I asked a wrong question here as there will not be a concrete answer, but good opinions. I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @Moon : I understand your perplexity and it will be hard for me to clarify the situation. IMHO, I see here an Observable (Event or Event's holder) and an Observer (function or function's holder). The two entities are linked by a string "event.name" instead of communicating explicitly (Event's holder calling function with args foo and bar). I think the Observer's intent is fully respected. On the opposite way, a Mediator would have been a third object that would have received the Event on one hand and called the function on the other hand.

Comment: @Moon : What certainly confuses you is that the linkage between the event and the callback is done by a "string" instead of a concrete object. But it is only a way to achieve a more loosely coupled design by using generic arguments instead of relying on objects. More information on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling - Section Methods for decreasing coupling